# Difference between generic type and wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm a newbie in Generic and my question is: what difference between two functions:

function 1:

```
public static <E> void funct1  (List<E> list1) {

}
```

function 2:

```
public static void funct2(List<?> list) {

}
```

Comment: If String refers to `java.lang.String`, I think funct2 is quite redundant in the wildcard expressions, since `java.lang.String` is final class and cannot be extended.

Comment: This is strange because technically you can't extend String since its a final class.

Comment: however there is no restriction on using function 2: as  it allows subclasses of String(though impossible) or the String class itself...

Comment: Best answer is given here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The first signature says: list1 is a List of Es.

The second signature says: list is a List of instances of some type, but we don't know the type.

The difference becomes obvious when we try to change the method so it takes a second argument, which should be added to the list inside the method:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Experiment {
    public static <E> void funct1(final List<E> list1, final E something) {
        list1.add(something);
    }

    public static void funct2(final List<?> list, final Object something) {
        list.add(something); // does not compile
    }
}
```

The first one works nicely. And you can't change the second argument into anything that will actually compile.

Actually I just found an even nicer demonstration of the difference:

```
public class Experiment {
    public static <E> void funct1(final List<E> list) {
        list.add(list.get(0));
    }

    public static void funct2(final List<?> list) {
        list.add(list.get(0)); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!! won't compile !!!!!!!!!
    }
}
```

One might as why do we need `<?>` when it only restricts what we can do with it (as @Babu_Reddy_H did in the comments). I see the following benefits of the wildcard version:

- The caller has to know less about the object he passes in. For example if I have a Map of Lists: `Map<String, List<?>>` I can pass its values to your function without specifying the type of the list elements. So
- If I hand out objects parameterized like this I actively limit what people know about these objects and what they can do with it (as long as they stay away from unsafe casting).

These two make sense when I combine them: `List<? extends T>`. For example consider a method `List<T> merge(List<? extends T>, List<? extends T>)`, which merges the two input lists to a new result list. Sure you could introduce two more type parameters, but why would you want to? It would be over specifying things.

- finally wildcards can have lower bounds, so with lists you can make the `add` method work, while `get` doesn't give you anything useful. Of course that triggers the next question: why don't generics have lower bounds?

For a more in depth answer see: [When to use generic methods and when to use wild-card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card) and http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ203

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's not just on puts. With a `List<E>`, you can write `E obj = list.get(0)`, but with `List<?>` you can only write `Object obj = list.get(0)`.

Comment: @Jens schauder. Both ? and E allows only object methods to invoke on the object. And one can add to List<E> and can't do same with List<?>. Then why do we need List<?> at all ?

Answer (score 9):

Generics makes the collection more type safe.

`List<E>` : E here is the Type Parameter, which can be used to determine the content type of the list, but there was `No` way to check what was the content during the `runtime`.

```
Generics are checked only during compilation time.
```

`<? extends String>` : This was specially build into java, to handle the problem which was with the Type Parameter. `"? extends String"` means this List can have

```
objects which IS-A String.
```

For eg:

```
Animal class
        Dog class extends Animal
        Tiger class extends Animal
```

So using  `"public void go(ArrayList<Animal> a)"` will `NOT accept` Dog or Tiger as its content but Animal.

`"public void go(ArrayList<? extends Animal> a)"` is whats needed to make the `ArrayList take in Dog and Tiger type.`

Check for references in Head First Java.

Comment: can i only use ? as shown in above example List<?> list? then what types of object is can store

Comment: "?" is used to make the collection being able to take the arguments from the called method which extends the type mentioned here          " <? extends Animal>".

Comment: List<?> list in this example user has not defined the type... then what type of object it will take?

Comment: List<?> indicates a list which has an unknown object type.

Comment: Why can't it be `public void go(ArrayList<T extends Animal> a)`?

Answer (score 3):

`List<E>` as a parameter type says that the parameter must be a list of items with any object type.  Moreover, you can bind the `E` parameter to declare references to list items inside the function body or as other parameter types.

The `List<?>` as a parameter type has the same semantics, except that there is no way to declare references to the items in the list other than to use `Object`.  Other posts give additional subtle differences.

Comment: sorry i have some mistake in my question and i edited the question.

Comment: @Gene can you please explain why in second function parameter must be a list of objects that derive from String. As Parameter is not defining its object type "List<?> list" so i think it can hold any type of object along with String.

Comment: Instead of saying "first" or "second", include the relevant code to avoid confusion (and edits to the OP).

Comment: The problem was no backquotes to prevent angle brackets from being interpreted as html tags.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a function that accepts a parameter that must be a list of items of E type.

the second example type is not defined

```
List<?> list
```

so you can pass list of any type of objects.

Comment: You can pass the first function a list of objects of any type, too - then `E` will be simply that type.

Answer (score 1):

I usually explain the difference between <**E**> and <**?**> by a comparison with logical quantifications, that is, universal quantification and existential quantification.

- corresponds to "forall E, ..."
- corresponds to "there exists something(denoted by ) such that ...."

Therefore, the following generic method declaration means that, for all class type **E**, we define `funct1`

```
public static <E> void funct1  (List<E>; list1) {

}
```

The following generic method declaration means that, for some existing class denoted by <**?**>, we define `funct2`.

```
public static void funct2(List<?> list) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Since your edit) Those two function signatures have the same effect to outside code -- they both take any `List` as argument. A wildcard is equivalent to a type parameter that is used only once.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those differences mentioned before, there is also an additional difference: You can explicitly set the type arguments for the call of the generic method:

```
List<Apple> apples = ...
ClassName.<Banana>funct2(apples); // for some reason the compiler seems to be ok
                               // with type parameters, even though the method has none

ClassName.<Banana>funct1(apples); // compiler error: incompatible types: List<Apple>
                                  //                 cannot be converted to List<Banana>
```

(`ClassName` is the name of the class containing the methods.)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, both wild card (?) and type parameter (E) will do the same for you. There are certain edges based on the use cases.
Let's say if you want to have a method which may have more than one params like:

```
public void function1(ArrayList<?> a, ArrayList<?> b){
 // some process
}

public <T> void function2(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b){
 // some process
}
```

in function1 a can be AL of String and b can be AL of the Integer so it is not possible to control the type of both the params but this is easy for the function2.
**We should use the Type Params (function 2) if we want to use the type later in the method or class**

There are some features in WildCard and Type param:

**WildCard(?)**

1. It support the upper and lower bound in the type while the Type param (E) supports only upper bound.

**Type Param(E)**

1. SomeTime we do not need to pass the actual type ex:

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> ai = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Double>  ad = new ArrayList<Double>();
   function2(ai, ad);
   //It will compile and the T will be Number.
   ```

In this case, the compiler infers the type argument for us based on the type of actual arguments