# Generic Wildcard Bounded Type vs Generic Bounded Type Parameter

Tags: java, oop, generics, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

While on a quest on understanding about Java Generics, I've come across this:

```
public static <T extends Number> int sumListElems(List<T> list){
   int total = 0;
   for(Number n: list)
       total += n.intValue();
   return total;
}
```

Suppose I have the following method that adds the elements of a List, restricted to Lists that holds a Number.

But what's the difference of that code to this one:

```
public static int sumListElems(List<? extends Number> list){
   int total = 0;
   for(Number n: list)
      total += n.intValue();
   return total;
}
```

Both of them compiles and executes as expected. What are differences between those two? Aside from the syntax? When would I prefer using the wildcard over the former?

Well, yes, using the wildcard approach, I can't add a new element on the list except null, or it won't compile. But aside from that?

Comment: These are equivalent in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763895/why-use-a-wild-card-capture-helper-method/30765179#30765179

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125616/java-generics-wildcards/15125788#15125788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference in this case. For more complex signatures, you may need to reuse the defined type so defining it is needed. Something like:

```
public static <T extends Number> void foo(T bar, List<T> myList)...
```

This guarantees not only that both `bar` and the elements of `myList` extend Number, but they are of the same type. You could not positively enforce that with the other syntax.