# What is a "?" type in Java, eg. Future<?>?

Tags: java, future

I just stumbled upon `Future<?>`. What is the '?'

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: It means it can return a `Future<ReferenceOfAnyClass>`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Not exactly "instance"---"any reference type" is more appropriate.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true, comment fixed.

Comment: I don't think it's fixed :) You still imply a "reference" to name the placeholder for a *type*. There are no instances, nor references to them, involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Future<?>` is an unbounded wildcard reference and is short for `Future<? extends Object>`. Meaning the generic can be of any type.

You could also have `Future<? extends T>`, where it has to extend a specific type T (upper bound), or `Future<? super T>` where is must be an ancestor of a specific type T (lower bound).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 5):

It is a wildcard expression used for generics.

See e.g.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

and

[Difference between generic type and wildcard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943137/difference-between-generic-type-and-wildcard-type)