# Generic vs wildcard unknown types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

When is it recommended to do:

```
public <E> boolean hasPropertyX(List<E extends User> alist);
```

versus

```
public boolean hasPropertyX(List<? extends User> alist);
```

It would appear they both work just as well.

Comment: `This reflects the fact that the type parameter is not being used to express any kind of interdependency between the type(s) of the argument(s), the return type and/or throws type. In the absence of such interdependency, generic methods are considered bad style, and wildcards are preferred.` Java Language Specification 8 §4.5.1-2. Basically, if there is a dependency on the type beyond the method, the first should be used. Otherwise, use the second.

Answer (score 4):

Without typed return value, the only difference I can think of is explicit typing of the first way of declaration during method call.

So for example you are using it inside typed class `C<K extends String>`

```
List<V extends String> input = ...;
boolean var = obj.hasProperty<K>(input);
```

will raise the compiler error. But why would any one want to do so...

Nice question even if most likely the answer is both are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly naming the generic type as `E` and not `?` has these uses (as far as I can think of):

0) To tie the return type to some part of the argument type - for example:

```
public <E> E getSomeElement(List<E> lst) { ... }
// ^ If we don't name the argument type as having E,
// then we can't specify the return type as being E
```

1) To tie some part of the argument type to some part of the enclosing type:

```
class Storage<E> {
    E item;
    public void replace(Storage<E> st) { item = st.item; }
    // ^ This wouldn't work if we wrote Storage<?> instead
}
```

2) To tie some *combination* of the argument types, return type, and enclosing type (see #0 and #1).

We can get away with the anonymous type name `?` if we don't care about the actual type. Here is a basic example:

```
boolean allEqual(List<?> lst, Object y) {
    for (Object x : lst) {  // Any reference can be stored as Object
        if (!y.equals(x))  // equals takes an Object
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// ^ We could also rewrite this example with List<E> and "E x".
```

Another example:

```
int intSum(List<? extends Number> lst) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Number x : lst)  // We only care that the list element is a Number
        sum += x.intValue();
    return sum;
}
// ^ We could also rewrite with List<E extends Number> and "E x".
```

Alternate reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 2):

I suppose in that particular example they both do work effectively the same way in terms of type checking. However, if you extend the generic type to require a base or superclass of some class it can be useful. e.g.

```
public <E extends User> boolean hasPropertyX(List<E> alist);
```

This at least enforces that you're receiving some subclass of `User`.

**EDIT**

You can use a wildcard to achieve the same thing:

```
public boolean hasPropertyX(List<? extends User> alist);
```

But this won't work if, for example, you want to use the generic for multiple parameters:

```
public <E extends Automobile> void crashAutos(List<E> list1, List<E> list2);
```

This enforces the generic type on both arguments, whereas the following code does not force the two lists to contain the same type:

```
public void crashAutos(List<? extends Automobile> list1, List<? extends Automobile> list2);
```

I could call that method with two different subclasses of the `Automobile` class:

```
List<Car> cars = ...
List<Truck> trucks = ...
crashAutos(cars, trucks);
```

Whereas using generics enforces the same type for both arguments.

Comment: You can do the same with the wildcard though, at least in the `drawAll` example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Good point. I tend to favor the generic over the wildcard as Java tends to complain about it less (unchecked cast warnings).

Answer (score 2):

Differences between generics and wildcard unknown types:

- Enforcing a relationship on the types of method arguments (Use Generics)
- Supporting multiple bounds (Use Generics)
- Supporting both upper and lower bounds (Use Wildcard)

The related question:

[When to use generic methods and when to use wild-card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card)

Answer (score 1):

Use `? extends` when you only need to *retrieve* from the List:

```
User getElement(List<? extends User> list, int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}
```

Use `? super` when you only need to *add* to the List:

```
void addElement(List<? super User> list, User u) {
    list.add(u);
}
```

Use `E extends` when you *both* need to retrieve and add:

```
<E extends User> void swapElements(List<E> list, int i, int j) {
    E temp = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(j));
    list.set(j, temp);
}
```

- `? extends User`: We don't know the exact type of the List, but we can retrieve a `User` from it.
- `? super User`: We don't know the exact type of the List, but we can put a `User` in it.
- `E extends User`: We don't necessarily know the exact type of the List but it conforms to constraints such that:

  - We give its actual type the name `E`.
  - We know `E` is at least `User`.
  - We can both retrieve `E` from the List and put `E` in the List.

See also:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the only one that really answers the question in a correct way. The others all read like "I don't know but this *may* happen or it may not who really knows?".