# Why use a wild card capture helper method?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Referring to : [Wildcard Capture Helper Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)

It says to create a helper method to capture the wild card.

```
public void foo(List<?> i) {
    fooHelper(i);
}        
private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
    l.set(0, l.get(0));
}
```

Just using this function below alone doesn't produce any compilation errors, and seems to work the same way. What I don't understand is: why wouldn't you just use this and avoid using a helper?

```
public <T> void foo(List<T> l) {
    l.set(0, l.get(0));
}
```

I thought that this question would really boil down to: what's the difference between wildcard and generics? So, I went to this: [difference between wildcard and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card).
It says to use type parameters:

> 1) If you want to enforce some relationship on the different types of method arguments, you can't do that with wildcards, you have to use type parameters.

But, isn't that exactly what the wildcard with helper function is actually doing? Is it not enforcing a relationship on different types of method arguments with its setting and getting of unknown values?

My question is: If you have to define something that requires a relationship on different types of method args, then why use wildcards in the first place and then use a helper function for it?

It seems like a hacky way to incorporate wildcards.

Comment: No, it's not i already looked at that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case it's because the [List.set(int, E)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method requires the type to be the same as the type in the list.

If you don't have the helper method, the compiler doesn't know if `?` is the same for `List<?>` and the return from `get(int)` so  you get a compiler error:

```
The method set(int, capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#2-of ?)
```

With the helper method, you are telling the compiler, the type is the same, I just don't know what the type is.

**So why have the non-helper method?**

Generics weren't introduced until Java 5 so there is a lot of code out there that predates generics.  A pre-Java 5 `List` is now a `List<?>` so if you were trying to compile old code in a generic aware compiler, you would have to add these helper methods if you couldn't change the method signatures.

Comment: Right, but if you ignore the wildcard function, and just use the helper you can still get the right output without any compilation errors.

Comment: @BrandonLing Yes that is true, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I understand why the compiler doesn't understand wildcards without the helper function, but the pre-java5 part answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: This answer explains 2 aspects of the issue that I couldn't understand, namely why is there a need to have a  helper method and how the helper method resolves the compile-time error. I found it confusing before this. I thought why not just write a generic method in the first place and be done with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I agree: Delete the helper method and type the public API. There's no reason not to, and every reason to.

Just to summarise the need for the helper with the wildcard version: Although it's obvious to us as humans, the compiler doesn't know that the unknown type returned from `l.get(0)` is the *same* unknown type of the list itself. ie it doesn't factor in that the parameter of the `set()` call comes from the same list object as the target, so it must be a safe operation. It only notices that the type returned from `get()` is unknown and the type of the target list is unknown, and two unknowns are not guaranteed to be the same type.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that we don't have to use the wildcard version.

It comes down to which API looks/feels "better", which is subjective

```
    void foo(List<?> i) 
<T> void foo(List<T> i)
```

I'll say the 1st version is better.

If there are bounds

```
    void foo(List<? extends Number> i) 
<T extends Number> void foo(List<T> i)
```

The 1st version looks even more compact; the type information are all in one place.

At this point of time, the wildcard version is the idiomatic way, and it's more familiar to programmers.

There are a *lot* of wildcards in JDK method definitions, particularly after java8's introduction of lambda/Stream. They are very ugly, admittedly, because we don't have variance types. But think how much uglier it'll be if we expand all wildcards to type vars.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I got a different reading from the question - OP asks what's the point of the `<?>` version while the `<T>` version works just fine.

Comment: OPs knows that `<?>` works from caller's side; but the implementer's side  needs a `<T>` helper. OP considers the `<?>` version a redundant middleman, asks why don't we just expose the `<T>` version.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java 14 Language Specification, Section 5.1.10 (PDF)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/jls14.pdf) devotes some paragraphs to why one would prefer providing the wildcard method `public`ly, while using the generic method `private`ly. Specifically, they say (of the `public` generic method):

> This is undesirable, as it exposes implementation information to the caller.

What do they mean by this? What exactly is getting exposed in one and not the other?

Did you know you can pass type parameters directly to a method? If you have a static method `<T> Foo<T> create()` on a `Foo` class -- yes, this has been most useful to me for static factory methods -- then you can invoke it as `Foo.<String>create()`. You normally don't need -- or *want* -- to do this, since Java can sometimes infer those types from any provided arguments. But the fact remains that you *can* provide those types explicitly.

So the generic `<T> void foo(List<T> i)` really takes two parameters at the language level: the element type of the list, and the list itself. We've modified the method contract just to save ourselves some time on the implementation side!

It's easy to think that `<?>` is just shorthand for the more explicit generic syntax, but I think Java's notation actually *obscures* what's really going on here. Let's translate into the language of type theory for a moment:

```java
/*                 Java *//* Type theory      */
             List<?>     ~~   ∃T. List<T>
    void foo(List<?> l)  ~~  (∃T. List<T>) -> ()
<T> void foo(List<T> l)  ~~   ∀T.(List<T>  -> ()
```

A type like `List<?>` is called an *existential type*. The `?` means that there **is some type** that goes there, but we don't know what it is. On the type theory side, `∃T.` means "there exists some T", which is essentially what I said in the previous sentence -- we've just given that type a name, even though we still don't know what it is.

In type theory, functions have type `A -> B`, where `A` is the input type and `B` is the return type. (We write `void` as `()` for silly reasons.) Notice that on the second line, our input type is the same existential list we've been discussing.

Something strange happens on the third line! On the Java side, it looks like we've simply named the wildcard (which isn't a bad *intuition* for it). On the type theory side we've said something _superficially very similar to the previous line: for **any type of the caller's choice**, we will accept a list *of that type*. (`∀T.` is, indeed, read as "for all T".) But the *scope* of `T` is now totally different -- the brackets have moved to include the output type! That's critical: we couldn't write something like `<T> List<T> reverse(List<T> l)` without that wider scope.

But if we don't *need* that wider scope to describe the function's contract, then reducing the scope of our variables (yes, even type-level variables) makes it easier to reason about those variables. The existential form of the method makes it abundantly clear to the caller that the relevance of the list's element type extends no further than the list itself.