# Benefits of using ? instead of T for type parameter in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have been programming in Java for several years and I do use generics but it seems my knowledge is incomplete because I don't fully understand the following:

What are the benefits of using `List<?>` instead of `List<T>`?

I do know that the question mark wildcard means any type (derived from `Object`) but so is `T` which can stand for any type. So is there a hidden benefit of using the former over the latter which I don't know about? or are they exactly the same?

How about `List<? extends T>` versus `List<E extends T>`?

Or `MyType<?, ?>` versus `MyType<E, T>`?

Edit: The thrust of my question here is different than another question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card) and none of the answers there answered my question. For example: I understand the difference between `List<?>` and `List<Long>` and when to use each one.  My question is regarding `List<?>` versus `List<T>` where both ? and T can stand for any type.

Comment: Really go see the other question and read the comments. But I tink that you should use names if you need to ensure type, and wildcard if you dont.

Comment: @Marcos, I appreciate your response but it is not helpful to me. I asked a very specific question, `List<?>` versus `List<T>` and you answered with a broad principle, which I already indicated I understood that principle with the `List<?>` versus `List<Long>` example.  I have read the answers to other question and they all give examples of how to apply the principle you mentioned but never directly answer my original question.

Comment: I just said that you can ensure types using name, its not really your answer.