# What is not valid in this assignment: `Map<String, Object> mObj = new HashMap<String, String[]>();`?

Tags: java, dictionary, compiler-errors, parameterized, incompatibletypeerror

in java, what is wrong with this assignment:

```
Map<String, Object> mObj = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

I get:

```
error: incompatible types: HashMap<String,String[]> cannot be converted to Map<String,Object>
```

Since `String[]` is an `Object`, that should work.
If I cast to an unparameterized `Map` like this: `Map<String, Object> mObj = (Map) new HashMap<String, String[]>();`, it is working but of course, I get a warning and it is dirty.

Further more, I feel that my first assignment should work.

Thank you !

PS: I cannot simply change `new HashMap<String, String[]>();` to `new HashMap<String, Object>();` because in reality, I call a method that returns a `Map<String, String[]>();` and of course, I cannot change this method. Thank you again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is is because generics do not support subtyping. `Number a = new Integer(5)` is valid case. But once you put generics it gives compilation error `ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<Integer>()` is not allowed. See if this link helps https://dzone.com/articles/5-things-you-should-know-about-java-generics to understand some guidelines on Generics.

Comment: Great link, I didn't knew how generics works and what were multiple bounds, and also, why you can't sub-type. But you can use wild card with extends and super as mentionned in the link, which might work here.

Answer (score 6):

Lets' see what could happen if what you wrote would be possible:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> foo = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
Map<String, Object> bar = foo;
bar.put("key",new Object());
String[] baz = foo.get("key"); // <-- ClassCastException
```

See the problem? A series of normal, mundane operations will cause `ClassCastException` in a place where you would expect it wouldn't be possible to emit one.

Edit: To summarize, `Map<String, Object>` is not a supertype of `Map<String, String>`, `Map<String, Object[]>` or `Map<String, String[]>`, so the assignment will not work, as the types aren't compatible. This is where wildcards come in; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: You're absolutely right but since I can bypass my error by casting to unparameterized `Map`, I still have the power to mess up the poor normal mundane operations ;) Don't you think it would have been more relevant to get only a unchecked warning instead of an incompatible types error ?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> mObj = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

But I can't tell you why your solution doesn't work.