# What purpose do generic constructors serve in Java?

Tags: java, generics, constructor

As everyone knows you can have a generic class in Java by using type arguments:

```
class Foo<T> {
    T tee;
    Foo(T tee) {
        this.tee = tee;
    }
}
```

But you can also have generic *constructors*, meaning constructors that explicitly receive their own generic type arguments, for example:

```
class Bar {
    <U> Bar(U you) {
        // Why!?
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to understand the use case. What does this feature let me do?

Comment: Maybe in situations like this: `<U> Bar(U a, U b)`?

Comment: This example is not very helpful. But generics would help you to establish contracts on arguments when U would have to extend another type or be an intersection type. (e.g. <U extends Serializable>)

Comment: Generic methods are useful. Constructors are similar to methods. It would be more effort to *forbid* generic constructors than to allow them, even if there's no particularly compelling use case.

Comment: Tip: if you _can_ do something it doesn't mean you _should_ do it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18176765/1398418 your question is almost a duplicate, there is no difference between a generic constructor and a generic method that doesn't return anything.

Comment: See [javafx.animation.KeyValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html#constructor.summary).  You can require multiple arguments to apply to consistent types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What does this feature let me do?

There are at least <s>three</s> two things it lets you do that you could not otherwise do:

1. express relationships between the types of the arguments, for example:

   ```
   class Bar {
       <T> Bar(T object, Class<T> type) {
           // 'type' must represent a class to which 'object' is assignable,
           // albeit not necessarily 'object''s exact class.
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. <withdrawn>
3. As @Lino observed first, it lets you express that arguments must be compatible with a combination of two or more unrelated types (which can make sense when all but at most one are interface types).  See Lino's answer for an example.

Comment: Isn't example 2 just going to deduce `T` as `Object` for unrelated types, thus letting anything through?

Comment: @user2357112, if you rely on type inference and have nothing else by which to constrain it, then yes, `Object` can be the type inferred in case 2.  Placing a lower bound is more interesting when there are other constraints in play alongside it.

Comment: The second case doesn't compile, you can't use a lower bound this way.

Comment: Ok, @Oleg, item 2 is withdrawn.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I think you nailed it with #1. It occurred to me that collections are probably the *natural* use case, but #1 is just as valid. See also my answer somewhere else on this thread.

Answer (score 24):

The use case I'm thinking of might be that some wants an Object which inherits from 2 Types. E.g. implements 2 `interfaces`:

```
public class Foo {

    public <T extends Bar & Baz> Foo(T barAndBaz){
        barAndBaz.barMethod();
        barAndBaz.bazMethod();
    }
}
```

Though I have never used it in production.

Comment: This is a good example. I didn't think of it! Although strictly speaking you can also solve this with `interface BarBaz extends Bar, Baz` or similar, this is probably a nicer way of saying the same. But it's, funnily enough, more *weakly* typed since there's no runtime type.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed exactly, and because the runtime type is unknown, or just not even really needed, this is more dynamic

Answer (score 19):

It's clear in the example you provided that `U` does not play any role in the class' constructor, as it effectively becomes an `Object` at runtime:

```
class Bar {
    <U> Bar(U you) {
        // Why!?
    }
}
```

But let's say that I wanted my constructor to only accept types that extend some other class or interface, as seen below:

```
class Foo<T extends Baz> {
    <U extends Bar> Foo(U u) {
        // I must be a Bar!
    }
}
```

Notice that the class already has a different generic type in use; this allows you to utilize a separate, unrelated generic type to the class definition.

Granted, I've never used something like this, and I've never seen it in use, but it's possible!

Comment: If all you need to know is that `u` is a `Bar`, then isn't it better practice to simply do `Foo(Bar u) {}`? I completely agree with your idea of being generic over descendants of `Baz` though - a good example is `<T extends Comparable>` for comparison-based-ordered data structures, like search trees

Comment: `<U extends Bar & Baz> Foo(U u)` where Bar and Baz are not related (eg two interfaces, both of which are required by the constructor).

Comment: Yes, that would have been better.

Comment: @Draco18s if `Bar` and `Baz` are interfaces in the context of your example, would you still use `extends` and not `implements`?

Comment: @musicman523 Yes, as `implements` is not the appropriate keyword, and will not compile.

Comment: @musicman523 [Yes, I'm sure](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/EasyRegistry.java#L32)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification both of you. From a language design standpoint, I'm curious about the reason that decision was made...maybe because `U` is a generic **interface** and not a **class**?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, this constructor

```
class Bar {
    <U> Bar(U you) {
        // Why!?
    }
}
```

is just like a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). It would make a lot more sense if you had multiple constructor arguments like this:

```
class Bar {
    <U> Bar(U you, List<U> me) {
        // Why!?
    }
}
```

Then you could enforce the constraint, that they have the same time with the compiler. Without making U a generic for the whole class.

Comment: The compiler could decide to insert Object as U to solve the problem, in what case you can still pass an int and a string object.

Comment: But note that unless you specify the type argument explicitly when you invoke the example constructor, Java can infer `U` to be `Object`, thus placing no restriction.

Comment: I get that it's like a generic method, in fact it *is* a generic method with a special name, `<init>`. But for a generic method, usually you're dealing with a `static` method in practice since for the main, instance methods can usually do what they need using the "genericness" they "inherit" from the class. I was wondering what you could possibly do with a generic constructor since constructors mainly initialize *class* state and it's hard to imagine scenarios where you set *class* state based on a generic dimension that's not available to the class...

Comment: @keuleJ, I think you're misunderstanding what @JohnBollinger is saying. The point is that `javac` your example is 100% identical *both* at compile time *and* at runtime to `Bar(Object you, Object me)`. So the generic parameter is redundant and slightly confusion-inducing. Whereas there are many uses of generic parameters that actually express meaningful constraints that can be statically verified at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

Because that unbound generic type erases to `Object`, it'd be the same as passing `Object` in your constructor:

```
public class Foo {
    Object o;

    public Foo(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

...but like passing a blank `Object`, unless you're doing something *clever*, this has little practical value.

You see benefits and wins if you pass in *bound* generics instead, meaning that you can actually have guarantees around the type that you care about.

```
public class Foo<T extends Collection<?>> {
    T collection;
    public Foo(T collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }
}
```

Effectively, this is more about flexibility than it being something revolutionary.  If you want the flexibility to pass in a specific category of types, then you have the power to do so here.  If you *don't*, then there's nothing wrong with standard classes.  It's merely here for your convenience, and since type erasure is still a thing, an unbound generic is the same (and has the same utility) as passing `Object`.

Comment: The OP seems focused on the generic constructor in his class `Bar`, having presented the generic class `Foo` primarily for contrast.  Though everything in this answer appears to be correct, I'm having trouble seeing how it responds to the generic constructor issue.