# In Java generic class, add extra generic constraints at constructor level?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, bounds

I have an interface called `Bar` and a generic class `Foo` parameterized on a type that *is a* `Bar`:

```
class Foo<B extends Bar> { }
```

My class has a general purpose constructor that takes a `Class` and a `Stream`:

```
class Foo<B extends Bar> {
    B[] bs;
    Foo(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) { // General ctor
        bs = someFunctionOf(clazz, stream);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a specialized constructor which is requires that its actual method parameter *both* is a `Bar` *and* an `enum` class such that I can call my general purpose constructor from the special constructor:

```
class Foo<B extends Bar> {
    B[] bs;
    Foo(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) { // General ctor
        bs = someFunctionOf(clazz, stream);
    }
    // FIX THIS ----+
    //              |
    //              ˅
    Foo(Class<Something> clazz) { // Special ctor
        // Can we make this work so Something is a Bar and an enum
        // and we can call the other constructor like this?
        this(clazz, Arrays.stream(clazz.getEnumConstants());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe mean `clazz.getEnumConstants()`?  Class `Class` has no method `getEnumeratedValues()`.

Comment: why not just 2 more special constructors?

Comment: @JohnBollinger - yeah - I screwed up the method name in my haste to generify the problem. Fixing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can write generic constructors.  We recently had [a question about them, and how they might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47806480/2402272).  In this way, you could provide a constructor that takes as an argument a Class representing a class that both extends some specific other class and implements interface `Bar`:

```
class Foo<B extends Bar> {
    B[] bs;
    Foo(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) { // General ctor
        bs = someFunctionOf(clazz, stream);
    }

    private B[] someFunctionOf(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) {
        return null;
    }

    <T extends SomeClass & Bar> Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But that does not quite get you where you want to be, because the bounds of the constructor's type argument `T` need to be explicit types.  Type variables such as the class's type parameter `B` do not serve, and without a way to connect `T` to `B`, the special generic constructor cannot invoke the general constructor.

But you *can* do this with a factory method instead of a special constructor:

```
class Foo<B extends Bar> {
    B[] bs;
    Foo(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) { // General ctor
        bs = someFunctionOf(clazz, stream);
    }

    private B[] someFunctionOf(Class<B> clazz, Stream<B> stream) {
        return null;
    }

    static <T extends Enum<T> & Bar> Foo<T> createEnumFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new Foo<>(clazz, Arrays.stream(clazz.getEnumConstants()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I had hoped there was a way to accomplish it with generic constructors but as you say there's no way to tie the bounds of the constructor's type parameter back to the class' type parameter. A bit frustrating! But I guess the alternative is to complicate the syntax in order to slightly simplify an obscure use case.

Answer (score -4):

This is possible by using the & operator: `<Something extends Bar & Enum<?>>`

Comment: On stackoverflow, you can mark something as a code block by putting it on its own line, and then indenting it. Since your code doesn't do this, it is parsed as html and rejected as invalid html