# LinkedList of type that implements the comparable interface

Tags: java, interface, primitive-types

I'm looking for how to pass as a parameter of a method a linkedList of a type which implements the Comparable interface.

```
 public static void mergeSort(LinkedList<Comparable> list){}
```

I tried that but when I pass a primitive type such as Integer as a parameter it doesn't work.
If someone have an idea ?

Comment: Hi Saryell please add the complete code to show how you are invoking the method and what parameters you're passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply let the compiler know that the input type `T` *extends* `Comparable<T>`.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(final LinkedList<T> list)
```

I would not use the `?`, which is a [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) and represents an *unknown type*.
Explicitly specifying the generic type is always better (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a bound parameter:

```
  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergeSort(LinkedList<T> list){}
```

This is taken from the method [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of raw types.

Answer (score 0):

Define a type parameter, and use that type parameter as the element type:

```
public static <C extends Comparable<? super C>> void mergeSort(LinkedList<C> list){}
```