# Java Generics: Explanation of Example on SO

Tags: java, generics

In another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943137/difference-between-generic-type-and-wildcard-type), the following example is given as a response to an OP:

```
public static <E> void funct1(final List<E> list1, final E something)
{
    list1.add(something);
}

public static void funct2(final List<?> list, final Object something)
{
    list.add(something); // does not compile
}
```

I have verified that funct1 compiles whereas funct2 does not.  However, I am unable to figure out why.

Comment: We don't know if `list` is a `List` containing `Object` instances.

Comment: What are the compile errors?

Answer (score 8):

A `List<?>` is a list of a specific yet unknown type.  The compiler can't allow a call on a method with the generic type parameter, because type safety can't be guaranteed.  It could be a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<Foo>`, and one shouldn't be able to add an `Object` to it.  The compiler must prevent this call with a compiler error to preserve the type safety that generics provides.

The method `funct1` compiles because you can always add an `E` to a `List<E>`; it's the same type reference: `E`.

Comment: What rules out type inference in this case?

Comment: There is no type to infer in the `List<?>` case.  The `?` wildcard doesn't infer the type from the object being added to the `List`.  The `?` wildcard means that we deliberately don't know or care about the actual type, as long as it is one specific type.

Answer (score 4):

[rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082293/438154) is right, but it's important to state that this doesn't only apply to `List`. It applies to all generic types.

If you declare a variable of a parameterized type with a wildcard `?`, you cannot use the corresponding type variable which the parameterized type declares for anything because you don't know what its value is. However, you can use `null` with it, since `null` can be used anywhere a value of some reference type is expected.

For example

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] str) throws Exception {
        Parameterized<?> exp = new Parameterized<String>();
        // below won't compile
        /*
           exp.something("tried my best");
           exp.something(666);
        */


        // below will compile
        exp.something(null);
    }    
}
class Parameterized<T> {
    public void something(T value) {}
}
```