# Second order generics seem to behave differently than first order generics

Tags: java, generics

I thought I have a reasonable grasp of generics. For example, I understand why

```
private void addString(List<? extends String> list, String s) {
    list.add(s); // does not compile
    list.add(list.get(0)); // doesn't compile either
}
```

Does not compile. [I even earned some internet karma with the knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943340/66686).

But I'd think by the same argument this shouldn't compile:

```
private void addClassWildcard(List<Class<? extends String>> list, Class<? extends String> c) {
    list.add(c);
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

Nor should this:

```
private void addClass(List<Class<? extends String>> list, Class<String> c) {
    list.add(c);
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

But both compile. Why? What is the difference to the example from the top?

I'd appreciate an explanation in common English as well as a pointer to the relevant parts of the Java Specification or similar.

Comment: The two cases are somewhat dissimilar. In the first case, the generic argument of `List` itself is a bounded wildcard, but in the second case it's the generic argument of the generic argument of `List` that has the wildcard. To make them the more similar, you could use `List<? extends Class<...>>`, but in the second case, the `List` adds no real value. It is pretty much the same as: `Class<? extends String> cls1 = c; Class<? extends String> cls2 = cls1;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second case is safe because all instances of `Class<String>` are instances of `Class<? extends String>`.

There is nothing unsafe about adding an instance of `Class<? extends String>` to a `List<Class<? extends String>` - you will get back an instance of `Class<? extends String>` using `get(int)`, `iterator()` etc - so it's allowed.

---

In a sense the wildcard inside `Class` gets only considered when an instance of that is actually encountered. Consider the following examples (switching from `String` to `Number` since `String` is final).

```
private void addClass(List<Class<? extends Number>> list, Class<Number> c) {
    list.add(c);
    list.add(list.get(0));
}

private void tryItSubclass() {
    List<Class<Integer>> ints = new ArrayList<>();

    addClass(ints, Number.class); // does not compile 
}
```

Here `ints` can only ever contain instances of `Class<Integer>` but `Number.class` is also a `Class<? extends Number>` with `?` captured as `Number` so the two types are not compatible.

```
private void tryItBound() {
    List<Class<Number>> ints = new ArrayList<>();

    addClass(ints, Number.class); // does not compile
}
```

Here `ints` can only ever contain instances of `Class<Number>` but `Integer.class` is also a `Class<? extends Number>` with `?` captured as `Integer` so the two types are not compatible.

```
private void tryItWildcard() {
    List<Class<? extends Number>> ints = new ArrayList<>();

    addClass(ints, Number.class); // does compile

    Class<? extends Number> aClass = ints.get(0);
}
```

---

The first case is unsafe because - were there a hypothetical class which extended `String` (which there isn't, because `String` is `final`; however, generics ignore `final`), a `List<? extends String>` might be a `List<HypotheticalClass>`. As such, you can't add a `String` to a `List<? extends String>`, because you expect everything in that list to be an instance of `HypotheticalClass`:

```
List<HypotheticalClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends String> list2 = list;
list2.add("");  // Not allowed, but pretend it is.
HypotheticalClass h = list.get(0);  // ClassCastException.
```

Comment: But String.class (instance of Class<String>) is not an instance of Class<HypotheticalClass>, which prooves your first sentence wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: First sentence "There is nothing unsafe about ..." is unclear for me.

Comment: @OleksandrPapchenko there's nothing unsafe about adding a `T` to a `List<T>`, right? So, if `T` is `? extend String`, there's nothing unsafe about that either.

Comment: @JensSchauder I'm not claiming that `Class<String>` is an instance of `Class<HypotheticalClass>` - I'm saying that it's a `Class<? extends String>`. `? extends String != HypotheticalClass` - it contains *all* classes which extend `String`.

Comment: I think I get it now. I added a couple of examples that make it clearer, at least to me. Let me know if you don't like the edit. I'll put it then in a separate answer.

Comment: The text under `tryItBound` does not seem to match the code, or am I confusing something here?!

Answer (score 8):

This has to do with capture conversion. Andy's answer is great but it doesn't explain how the specification works. My answer here is long because, well, this is a pretty dense part of the JLS, but I don't see it explained much and it's not that difficult if you walk through it step-by-step.

Capture conversion is a process whereby the compiler takes a type with wildcards and replaces (some of) the wildcards with types which are not wildcards.

The supertypes of a parameterized type with wildcards are the supertypes of that type after capture conversion:

> [*4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)
>
> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (*n* > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<R1,...,Rn>` where at least one of the `Ri` (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*) is a wildcard type argument, are the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<X1,...,Xn>` which is the result of applying capture conversion to `C<R1,...,Rn>`.

The types of the members (including methods) of a parameterized type with wildcards are the types of the members of that type after capture conversion:

> [*4.5.2. Members and Constructors of Parameterized Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.2)
>
> Let `C` be a generic class or interface declaration with type parameters `A1,...,An`, and let `C<T1,...,Tn>` be a parameterization of `C` where, for 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*, `Ti` is a type (rather than a wildcard). Then:
>
> - *[skipped for irrelevance]*
>
> If any of the type arguments in the parameterization of `C` are wildcards, then:
>
> - The types of the fields, methods, and constructors in `C<T1,...,Tn>` are the types of the fields, methods, and constructors in the capture conversion of `C<T1,...,Tn>`.

#### So how does capture conversion work?

Suppose we are given the following class declaration (chosen to illustrate some parts of the process more completely):

```
class C<V, W extends List<V>> {

    void m(V v, W w) {
    }
}
```

And the following use of this type:

```
C<Number, ?> c = new C<>();

Double       tArg = 1.0;
List<Number> uArg = new ArrayList<>();
c.m(tArg, uArg);
```

How do we determine the type of `c.m` for the purpose of determining [if the argument types may be assigned to the parameter types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)?

Well, to start with, as stated above, the parameter types of `c.m` are the parameter types of `m` in the capture conversion of `C<Number, ?>`:

> [5.1.10. Capture Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)
>
> Let `G` name a generic type declaration with *n* type parameters `A1,...,An` with corresponding bounds `U1,...,Un`.

For this example:

- `G` is `C`.
- `A1` is `V` with bound `U1` which is `Object`.
- `A2` is `W` with bound `U2` which is `List<V>`.

> There exists a *capture conversion* from a parameterized type `G<T1,...,Tn>` to a parameterized type `G<S1,...,Sn>`...

For this example, `G<T1,...,Tn>` is `C<Number, ?>`:

- `T1` is `Number`.
- `T2` is `?`.

> ..., where, for 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*:
>
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `?`, then `Si` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` and whose lower bound is the `null` type.
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `? extends Bi`, then `Si` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `glb(Bi, Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn])` and whose lower bound is the `null` type.
>
>   `glb(V1,...,Vm)` is defined as `V1 & ... & Vm`.

`Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` is the bound of `Ai` (the type parameter) with the substitution of each type argument for each corresponding type parameter. (This is why I declared `C` with a type parameter whose bound references another type parameter: because it illustrates what this part does.)

In our example, for `T2` (which is `?`), `S2` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `U2` (which is `List<V>`) *with* the substitution of `Number` for `V`.

`S2` is therefore a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `List<Number>`.

For simplicity, I'm going to ignore the case where we have a bounded wildcard, but a bounded wildcard is essentially just capture converted to a fresh type variable whose bound is `BoundOfWildcard & BoundOfTypeParameter`. Also, if a wildcard has a lower bound (`super`), then the fresh type variable has the lower bound too.

If `Ti` is *not* a wildcard, then:

> - Otherwise, `Si = Ti`.

So in our example, `S1` is just `T1` which is `Number`.

And that:

> Capture conversion is not applied recursively.

which we'll get to later.

We now know that:

- `S1` is `Number`.
- `S2` is some type variable `FRESH extends List<Number>` which the compiler's just created.

Therefore, the capture conversion of `C<Number, ?>` is `C<Number, FRESH>`.

Now we can actually answer the question: are `Double` and `List<Number>` assignable to `Number` and `FRESH extends List<Number>`, respectively? In the former case, yes. In the latter case, no.

This is for the same reasons that the expression wouldn't compile if we declared a type variable in this way ourselves:

```
static <FRESH extends List<Number>> void n() {
    C<Number, FRESH> c = new C<>();

    Double       tArg = 1.0;
    List<Number> uArg = new ArrayList<>();
    c.m(tArg, uArg);
}
```

[The supertypes of a type variable are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2):

> - The direct supertypes of a type variable are the types listed in its bound.

Therefore, `List<Number>` may *not* be assigned to `FRESH` because `List<Number>` is a a *supertype* of `FRESH`.

By analogy, we could also declare a class this way:

```
class Fresh extends List<Number> {}
C<Number, Fresh> c = new C<>();

Double       tArg = 1.0;
List<Number> uArg = new ArrayList<>();
c.m(tArg, uArg);
```

That might be more familiar, and isn't really all that different with respect to how the relationship between types works in this case.

In other words, in our original example:

```
C<Number, ?> c = new C<>();

Double       tArg = 1.0;
List<Number> uArg = new ArrayList<>();
c.m(tArg, uArg);
//        ^^^^ this
```

is just a more complicated version of this:

```
Object o = ...;
String s = o; // Error: attempting to assign a supertype to its subtype.
```

and (at the end of the day) doesn't compile for roughly the same reason.

#### In Summary

Capture conversion takes wildcards and turns them in to type variables (temporarily). After that, it's just the regular rules of subtyping that cause these errors.

So for example, given the code in the question:

```
private void addString(List<? extends String> list, String s) {
    list.add(s); // does not compile
    list.add(list.get(0)); // doesn't compile either
}
```

While viewing the expression `list.add(s)`, the compiler sees something like this:

```
private <CAP#1 extends String>
void addString(List<? extends String> list, String s) {
    ((List<CAP#1>) list).add( s );
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

The error produced is as follows:

> ```
> error: no suitable method found for add(String)
>         list.add(s); // does not compile
>             ^
>     method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
>     method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>     CAP#1 extends String from capture of ? extends String
> ```

In other words, the compiler found methods `add(CAP#1)` and `String` is inconvertible to the type variable `CAP#1`.

While viewing the expression `list.add(list.get(0))`, the compiler sees something like this:

```
private <CAP#1 extends String, CAP#2 extends String>
void addString(List<? extends String> list, String s) {
    list.add(s);
    ((List<CAP#2>) list).add( ((List<CAP#1>) list).get(0) );
}
```

The error produced is as follows:

> ```
> error: no suitable method found for add(CAP#1)
>         list.add(list.get(0)); // doesn't compile either
>             ^
>     method Collection.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#2)
>     method List.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#2)
>   where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
>     CAP#1 extends String from capture of ? extends String
>     CAP#2 extends String from capture of ? extends String
> ```

In other words, the compiler found that `list.get(0)` returns `CAP#1` and found methods `add(CAP#2)` but `CAP#1` is inconvertible to `CAP#2`.

([Source for errors.](https://ideone.com/lS22Xm))

#### So why do `List<Class<?>>` and other similar types work?

Recall that:

> - Otherwise, *[if `Ti` is not a wildcard type]*, `Si = Ti`.

And that:

> Capture conversion is not applied recursively.

So if `Ti` is a parameterized type like `Class<?>`, then `Si` is just `Class<?>`. Also, since capture conversion is not applied recursively, the algorithm just stops after converting `T1,...,Tn` to `S1,...,Sn`. The new type is not capture-converted and the bounds of the fresh type variables are not capture-converted.

We can also verify that this is indeed what the compiler does by causing some interesting errors:

```
Map<?, List<?>> m = new HashMap<>();

List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(m);
```

This produces the following error:

> ```
> error: no suitable method found for add(Map<CAP#1,List<?>>)
>         list.add(m);
>             ^
>     […]
> ```

([Source.](https://ideone.com/U7TeSn))

Note that the type argument `List<?>` in the `Map` type capture converts to itself.

And another:

```
Map<?, ? extends List<?>> m = new HashMap<>();

List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(m);
```

This produces the following error:

> ```
> error: no suitable method found for add(Map<CAP#1,CAP#2>)
>         list.add(m);
>             ^
>     […]
>   where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3 are fresh type-variables:
>     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
>     CAP#2 extends List<?> from capture of ? extends List<?>
>     CAP#3 extends Object from capture of ?
> ```

([Source.](https://ideone.com/2jYOdZ))

Note that this time, while `? extends List<?>` is capture-converted, the bound `List<?>` is not.

#### *Finally*

The answer to the question as-stated is that the wildcard in `List<? extends String>` is capture-converted to a fresh type variable but the wildcard in `List<Class<? extends String>>` is not.

Comment: I just wanted to say how _incredibly_ valuable this answer is. Thanks (these many years later) for your time explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

Your example misses the fact (at least I think so), that (going to `Integer` and `Number` for existing examples) `List<Class<Integer>>` is no valid instance of `List<Class<? extends Number>>`.

So, this does not compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Class<Integer>> intClasses = new LinkedList<>();
    addClass(intClasses, Number.class); // compiler error
}

private static void addClass(List<Class<? extends Number>> list, Class<Number> c) {
    list.add(c);
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```