# java generics bounded wildcards `? super ? extends T`

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I stumble upon this problem million of times and I can't wrap my head around it.

Let's assume I have a stream `seq` of type `Stream<? extends T>` and I want to execute a `forEach` on its elements.

The type of the consumer now becomes a `Consumer<? super ? extends T>`, now how does java treat a generic type `? super ? extends T` ?

Is it the equivalent of `? super T`, because the generic type `? extends T` is considered as a `T` in this example.

Someone please provide the exact procedure of how the java compiler treats the following situations.

Comment: I think it's equivalent to `? super T`. If you have a `Stream<? extends Number>`, `Consumer<Integer>` would be invalid, but `Consumer<Number>` and `Consumer<Object>` should still be applicable. Shouldn't be hard to test.

Comment: The type of the consumer is, in reality, `? super U`. where `U`==`? extends T`. In effect for code, this is similar to `? super T`, since you're accepting a contravariant bound of something which extends `T`. Look up "covariance vs contravariance".

Comment: @Rogue I will for sure

Comment: The type of the `Stream` is capture converted for the purpose of considering the parameter type to `forEach`, so the parameter type to `forEach` actually becomes something like `Consumer<? super CAP#1>` where `CAP#1` is the result of capture conversion on the type argument `? extends T`. I explained capture conversion in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061947/2891664) and TBH I don't really feel like writing another capture conversion answer today. Capture conversion is the "real" answer.