# Difference between <V extends SomeInterface> and <? extends SomeInterface>

Tags: java, generics

I do not get the difference between:

```
<V extends SomeInterface> BinaryOperator<V> method() {...}
```

and:

```
BinaryOperator<? extends SomeInterface> method() {...}
```

The whole snippet:

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Scratch {

    interface SomeInterface {
        boolean isEditable();
    }

    static class One implements SomeInterface {

        public String specificMethod() {
            return "Hello";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEditable() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(new One())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    // cannot resolve method 'specificMethod' in 'SomeInterface' in collector:
                    key -> key.specificMethod(),
                    Function.identity(),
                    chooseNotEditable()
                ));
    }

    // works:
    // static <V extends SomeInterface> BinaryOperator<V> chooseNotEditable() {
    //
    // Doesn't work:
    // static BinaryOperator<? extends SomeInterface> chooseNotEditable() {

        return (current, other) -> current.isEditable() ? current : other;
    }
}
```

I'm doing this because I want to have one generic mergeFunction to many implementations of  `SomeInterface`. The commented solution works, but I want to understand why the version with the wildcard is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (V) is called a generic. This means that you define a method for a certain type. You can reuse this type in several lines of code. The type stays the same.
Then the second (?) is called a wildcard. This means that you define a method for an object of which you do not know the type. In further lines of code, you probably will not call specific methods on the object.

Please also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943137/difference-between-generic-type-and-wildcard-type).

Kind regards,
Marja